# Why does '.'/3 silently convert an associative list into a dict?

Tags: dictionary, swi-prolog

I was doing some type testing in SWI-Prolog and stumbled upon the differences between dicts and list of `Key=Value` terms. Or rather, I stumbled upon their similarities.

According to the [SWI-Prolog manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) dicts are "structures with named arguments" of the form `Tag{Key1:Value1, Key2:Value2, ...}`. The manual mentions the predicates `'.'/3` ([section 4.2.1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dict-functions)) and `get_dict/3`([section 4.2.2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dict-predicates)) to extract values from dicts (other predicates and functional-notation deliberately omitted). The difference between the predicates is that `'.'/3` raises an exception if the dict does not contain the desired key while `get_dict/3` fails silently. Lists, however, are no dicts even if there are predicates transforming lists (of key-value associations, e.g., `key:value` or `key-value`) into dicts. Nevertheless, `' .'/3` silently transform those lists into dicts, while `get_dict/3` does not (tested with SWI-Prolog 8.2.2)?

```
?- is_dict([key=value]).
false.

?- get_dict(key, [key=value], V).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `[key=value]' (a list)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] get_dict(key,[key=value],_25650)
ERROR:    [9] <user>

?- get_dict(no_key, [key=value], V).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `[key=value]' (a list)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] get_dict(no_key,[key=value],_29084)
ERROR:    [9] <user>

?- '.'([key:value], key, V).
V = value.

'.'([key=value], no_key, V).
ERROR: key `no_key' does not exist in _31746{key:value}
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] '$get_dict_ex'(no_key,_31802{key:value},_31798)
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following query:

```
?- listing('.').
'$dicts':'.'(Data, Func, Value) :-
    (   '$get_dict_ex'(Func, Data, V0)
    *-> Value=V0
    ;   is_dict(Data, Tag)
    ->  eval_dict_function(Func, Tag, Data, Value)
    ;   is_list(Data)
    ->  (   is_dict_func(Func)
        ->  dict_create(Dict, _, Data),           % <== TRANSFORM LIST INTO DICT!!!
            '$get_dict_ex'(Func, Dict, Value)
        ;   '$type_error'(atom, Func)
        )
    ;   '$type_error'(dict, Data)
    ).
```

As we can see, the predicate `'.'\3` actually converts a list into a dictionary, before accessing the key-related value (code comment added by me). Except for the code listing, I didn't find any documentation on this fact.